# Materialized view Vs Temp tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql

I have a base transaction table. Then I have around 15 intermediate steps, where I'm combining dimension tables, performing some aggregation and implementing business logic. The way I'm handling currently is creating temporary tables for intermediate stages and post these 15 steps populating the final result in a physical table. It it a better approach or using materialized view instead of these intermediate temp tables is a better approach. If using materialized views for the intermediate steps is a better approach, can you kindly let me know why?

Have already tried scripting both the approaches, scripted 15 intermediate steps as global temporary table as well as Materialized view. I found marginal improvement in performance in MVs when compared to Temp tables, but comes at the cost of excess physical storage. Not sure which is the best practice and why

Comment: One major difference is: data in temporary tables persist only in your current session. Consider this also for the case when an error happens in your process.

Comment: Yes, When I'm doing validation, will keep it as physical table, when deploying it in production, will convert the intermediate steps as temp tables and drop the physical tables.

Comment: If I were you, I'd be looking to implement all 15 steps using as few GTTs as possible. I.e. combining as many steps as possible into a single sql statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary tables write to disk, so there's I/O costs for both reading and writing. Also most sites don't manage their temporary tables properly and they end up on the default temporary tablespace, which is the same TEMP tablespace everybody uses for sorting, etc. So there's potential for resource contention there.

Materialized views are intended for materializing aspects of our data set which are commonly reused by many different queries. That's why the most common use case is for storing higher level aggregates of low level data. That doesn't sound like the use case you have here. And lo!

> I'm doing a complete refresh of MVs and not a incremental refresh

So nope.

> Then I have around 15 intermediate steps, where I'm combining dimension tables, performing some aggregation and implementing business logic.

This is a terribly procedural way of querying data. Sometimes there's no way of avoiding this, especially in certain data warehouse scenarios. However, it doesn't follow that we need to materialize the outputs of those queries. An alternative approach is to use WITH clauses. The output from one WITH subquery can feed into lower subqueries.

```
    with sq1 as ( 
         select whatever
                , count(*) as t1_tot
         from t1
         group by whatever
   ) , sq2 as (
         select sq1.whatever
                , max(t2.blah) as max_blah
         from sq1
              join t2 on t2.whatever = sq1.whatever
   ) , sq3 as ( 
         select sq2.whatever
                ,(t3.meh + t3.huh) as qty
         from sq2
              join t3 on t3.whatever = sq2.whatever
         where t3.something >= sq2.max_blah
   )
   select sq1.whatever
          ,sq1.t1_tot
          ,sq2.max_blah
          ,sq3.qty
   from sq1
        join sq2 on sq2.whatever = sq1.whatever
        join sq3 on sq3.whatever = sq1.whatever
```

Not saying it won't be a monstrous query, the terror of the department. But it will probably perform way better than your MViews ot GTTs. (Oracle may choose to materialize those intermediate result sets but [we can use hints to affect that](http://dbaora.com/with-clause-and-hints-materialize-and-inline/).)

You may even find from taking this approach that some of your steps are unnecessary and you can combine several steps into one query. Certainly in real life I would write my toy statement above as one query not a join of three subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

From what you said, I'd say that using (global or private, depending on database version you use) temporary tables is a better choice. Why? Because you are "calculating" something, storing results of those calculations into some tables, reusing them for additional processing. All of that - if it can't be done without *temporary* tables - is to be done with tables.

Materialized view is, as its name says, a *view*. It is a result of some query, but - opposed to "normal" views, it actually takes space. Can be refreshed (either on demand, when source data is changed, or based on a schedule). Yes, it has its advantages, though I can't see any in what you are currently doing.

Comment: Even the same calculation or joins with dimension table, I can do it using Materialized view as well, but it takes space. On the longer run, will I have any improved performance by using Materialized view instead of Temp tables in the intermediate steps? As well as if Materialized views has advantages, in what scenario it has to be used to leverage it's advantage?

Comment: In terms of query performance I found a MVs are marginally better than Temp tables. That might be because my data volume is less and I'm doing a complete refresh of MVs and not a incremental refresh.

Comment: @Zaynul: what about it? I don't understand what you mean. Temporary tables can be indexed as any other tables; probably will contain much less data than the original source tables, so - blindly guessing, without any measurable info I currently have - I'd expect performance to be better. Durgaprasad, you'll have to test it. If you choose to to use MVs, don't forget to index columns you'll be using in WHERE clauses. Note that both MV *and* index(es) will take space, but that's OK if performance is good (and you have enough space, of course).